# jQuery slideDown + Table row issue + IE browser

Tags: jquery

I know its an old problem and i found many ppl hav suggested some gud solutions..
still in my case it din work..

I have a row like

----> this tr is in invisible mode.

`<tr id="test" > 
    <td>
        <table>
             <tr></tr>
             <tr></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>`

So when i am applying slideUp/Down effect its  working the same as show/hide() since it is row so animation is not supported.
So tried wrap it in div and do the same.But that also did the same as show/hide..

Any idea why so??or any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this is to wrap the content of  element into a div and apply slideup/down on that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know you question exactly.. but I do use .fadeIn() and .fadeOut on rows and it works fine.

Comment: thanks for the reply..
I did try that one but it not giving the slideDown effect..which is the requirement i have..

Comment: @ratan well `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` aren't going to slide things anywhere, as their names suggest. You're probably going to have to alter your requirements sonewhat.

Comment: @JamWaffles  there are solutions given for appliying slide effect to rows as well but for me its not working..im trying to append div to the rows..lets c if it works..